# How to debug Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2005

What are the detailed steps on how to debug the Delphi IDE?

I understand, from other posts, that one needs to create a project and, in the project's debugger settings, set the project's "host application" to Delphi (`C:\Program Files\Borland\BDS\3.0\Bin\bds.exe`). Then, when the project is run in the debugger (by pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key), a second instance of the Delphi IDE should appear.

I have managed to do the above step. However, when I run the project in debugger mode, I don't see any second instance of the Delphi IDE opening.

#### Motivation

There is a [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) component, for which I do have the source code, that builds, compiles and installs fine. But, when it is placed on a form in a project, Delphi hangs when you close the form. So, I want to find out why Delphi is freezing on exit with this component on a form. (It hangs at design-time, when closing the project).

Comment: What do you mean by debug: seeing the other process (the second IDE) running under the debugger (the first IDE), or do you actually want to find and remove a certain bug? Asking because the question and title make it look like you want to debug the IDE itself! You can surely see it running under your debugger, but finding and removing bugs is an other story: you need source code for that, and you don't have source code for the IDE!

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. There is a VCL component, for which I do have the source code, that builds, compiles and installs fine. But, when it is placed on a form in a project, Delphi hangs when you close the form. So, I want to find out why Delphi is freezing on exit with this component on a form.

Comment: I added your clarifications as an edit to the question itself, because that's where everyone will look for clarifications. Asking for more clarifications: Are you saying you've got a DPK as the only active project, you set it's host application to the Delphi IDE, hit Run and it doesn't launch the IDE? Does it do anything else? Example: does it give you an error message?

Comment: Take a look at something like CodeSite from Raize. Add Codesite.Send lines for all the parameters and ins and outs of your component's operation. There is an IDE utility to help do this for all functions. This will help you learn what is happening, and why. And it doesn't interfere with the operation like popping up messageboxes etc.

Comment: https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/2018/12/debugging-the-rad-studio-ide/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your project is most likely an EXE-type. EXE type projects don't need host applications so the setting is ignored, no other IDE is started. At a minimum, you should make your project a DLL-type: that will start the second IDE, but it will not be very helpful.

The technique you mentioned is usually used to debug your *design time package* projects. Create a design-time package project, install it into the IDE, set the project's host application to be the IDE, set some breakpoints, hit <kbd>F9</kbd> and a second copy of Delphi will start.

You can also "debug" the Delphi IDE by manually starting a second copy yourself and then using the "Attach to process" command from the "Run" menu, but that's not going to be very useful since you can't easily find *your* code to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. There is a VCL component, for which I do have the source code, that builds, compiles and installs fine. But, when it is placed on a form in a project, Delphi hangs when you close the form. So, I want to find out why Delphi is freezing on exit with this component on a form.

Comment: Thank you Cosmin Prund. Your answer worked regarding getting the 2nd copy of IDE running. I can now look at debugging the component.

Answer (score 3):

I would first check if the hang occurs at run-time as well as at design-time.  Instantiate the component dynamically in your run-time code.  If the hang sstill occurs, then you can step through the component's source code normally using a single debugger instance.  You do not need to debug into a running IDE instance unless the behavior only occurs within the IDE process.

Comment: The hanging only occurs in design-time not runtime. If I create a simple projet, with one form, place the problem component on it and run the project, it runs fine and even terminates fine. But, when I try and close the project in the IDE or exit Delphi with that project open, Delphi hangs. Hence I want to find out what is causing the IDE to hang.

Answer (score 1):

First find and open the component packages, turn both the runtime and designtime package build options from Release to Debug, if they aren't already, and rebuild.

Then save a project group containing both the package projects (one designtime and one runtime, in some exceptional cases, people only have one package, which is designtime+runtime in one).

Then follow the steps to set BDS.exe as the Host Application.

I would be tempted to add some `OutputDebugString` messages to the component that you know is broken:

Constructor:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
    inherited;
    // other stuff.
    OutputDebugString('Created TMyComponent');
end;
```

Destructor:

```
destructor TMyComponent.Destroy(AOwner:TComponent);
begin
    OutputDebugString('Destructor TMyComponent starts');
    inherited;
    // other stuff.
    OutputDebugString('Destructor TMyComponent finish');
end;
```

Finalization section of the unit that TMyComponent is in:

```
 finalization
      OutputDebugString('Finalization section for Unit MyComponentUnit');
 end.
```

Looking at the output Events page in the delphi debugger, you can figure out how far the code got, and even if you don't get an exception breakpoint that you can use to locate the flaw fairly accurately, you can use either OutputDebugString messages like the above, or you can even just set [Non Breaking Breakpoints](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31263) in delphi, and turn off the breakpoint property "Break on exception" and instead set up a "log message".  These messages (breakpoint messages) have the benefit of not requiring any damage to your component in order to add some simple "print-statement-debug" like capabilities to your debugging toolkit.

Comment: The OP said this is about a "...a VCL component, for which **I do have the source code**". It doesn't seem to be about DPK's with missing source, unless you know something that's not posted here.

Comment: Good point. My answer was fundamentally boolean-opposite of what was needed. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If the second instance of Delphi is not launching then you have the path to bds.exe incorrect.

Comment: The path is correct as I got the location by right-clicking on the Delphi 2005 (bds.exe) shortcut icon and copying it's target location. If I past the whole path into a explorer window, Delphi 2005 also starts. So path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to debug a component installed into a package in the IDE or to debug the IDE itself. I have article about this [here](https://gabrielmoraru.com/debug_ide_or_vcl_components/).
(Sorry, Stack Overflow copied the text but refused to copy the formatting and the pictures)

**Method 1: Attach to process**

One possible solution is to run two Delphi instances in parallel and attach one instance (this will be the debugger) to the other one (the debugged one).

For this, click Run -> Attach to process. The first started instance will have a lower PID:

I don’t use this method, personally.

**Method 2: Debug with “Run -> Load process”.**

First, if the IDE does not start at all, disable the broken packages from registry so we can load the IDE. Simply delete the entry (the broken package) from “Known Packages” if the crash is in a “normal” VCL package. This is the registry key where we can alter user-defined packages paths directly:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Known Packages

Or, if the crash is in an IDE package:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Known IDE Packages

Now, start the first instance of Delphi. This will be the debugger.

In the “Run -> Load process” box we enter the path to Delphi (bds.exe) file:

Click “Load”. Delphi will load a new Delphi process, but it will be paused!

We need to press “Run” to resume the second Delphi instance:

The second instance now starts, and it raises two exceptions during startup. They are always there but normally we don’t see them (silent exceptions), but now that we debug the IDE, the debugger catches them. The errors are EFOpenFile and ESanctSocketException. Both are because of Delphi licensing/protection system. Just ignore them.

Depending on the Delphi version, we might see an EAccessViolation and an EParseError. Ignore these two also.

At this point, you might get lost and because don’t know which instance is the debugger and which is the debugged one. But there is a simple trick to figure out which is which: check the Desktop Speed Settings box. The debugger session will be in “Debug layout” mode while the “normal” (debugged) session will be in “Default layout” (or whatever we renamed it) mode:

Forget about the first instance (the debugger) and use the second instance to program as you normally do. Go to “Components-> Install component” and re-enable the disabled (the misbehaving) BPLs. As soon as we click the misbehaving package to install it into the IDE, it should crash.

Now, the debugger (the first instance) will step in, and it will take us to the source code of the component that generated the crash.

The path of that unit should be present in the “Debug DCUs” otherwise we might not be able to step into the source code.

**How does this Delphi in Delphi trickery work?**

If in the second instance of Delphi, we write in our program code to trigger a standard exception, the exception is caught in that instance, because that instance is debugging our (exe) program:

However, at design time, the components run inside the IDE. Whatever exception is raised in the component, IS an exception in the IDE itself. That instance of the IDE cannot debug itself:

So, the exception is caught in the first instance, because the first instance is the debugger for the second instance:

Read those sentences a few more times. If you don’t understand them, you are either stupid, or I haven’t explained them properly

So, what the hell, let’s crash the IDE. To crash the IDE, we create a dummy control that raises an exception when it is created.

We install it into the IDE:

Now we drag and drop the control on a form, and we get the exception because its constructor was called. The first instance of Delphi (the debugger) shows:

If we press the break button, we see the call stack:

Now we can truly debug that component.

When done with debugging, we press F9 to return to the second instance which also, finally, shows the exception:

Great! We just demonstrated that the exception in the TBrokenPanel was caught by session one which was also able to show the actual line of code that raised the exception.

**Method 3: Host application (Recommended)**

Install the package you want to debug into the IDE. Click the “Run -> Process parameters” main menu. Enter Delphi as the host application:

Set some breakpoints in your package, at the point where you want to stop.

Press F9. Normally when you don’t set the Host application field, pressing F9 will give us an error message that tells us that we cannot run a package (of course, you can only run applications, not packages):

However, in this case, because we set the Host application field, that host application (Delphi) will start. There we will be able to debug our package.

This is the recommended method because it is easy to set the breakpoints.

Once you are done debugging, don’t forget to clear the “Host application” field.

Note that this field/setting is “per project” even though it seems to pe “global”.

**Method 4: External tools**

External tools like MadShi and EurekaLog can also take control when crashes in the IDE occur and can show the call stack trace. Much easier and more convenient, but costs money.

More about Eureka and MadShi here.

**Method 5: Start Delphi in “safe” mode**

One day we might find that our beloved Delphi refuses to start. The IDE simply crashes at. In some cases, it might say something “Access violation in Something.BPL”. In this case find that BPL/plugin and delete it (or rename it). But sometimes, Delphi doesn’t show which plugin is causing the crash.

In this case, we can start a “mint” Delphi instance, like the first time after we installed Delphi. No extra 3rd party plugins. All new and fresh.

Once started this special instance, we can install our plugins and packages one by one and see which is the one that crashes our IDE.

Instead of reinstalling Delphi to get that “mint” instance we can start it by passing the –r parameter to it. This is explained in the “How to start a mint Delphi instance” chapter below.

---

Disclaimer: The SO EULA says that I need to disclaim that I am affiliated to that website, so here I am.