# Delphi 7 IDE freezes trying to open a specific project

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

I'm getting pretty desperate here. I've looked at this question which seems to have a similar question to me:

[Delphi IDE is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430699/delphi-ide-is-not-visible/20432742?noredirect=1#comment32036322_20432742)

Unfortunately it appears to only apply to newer versions of Delphi, and I am using Delphi 7 which doesn't have the discussed .dproj file extensions.

Basically my project will not open up in Delphi. My colleague has gotten the latest source from Perforce and it works for him, but doing the same thing does not work for me on my machine. I have installed one plugin about 2 weeks ago, which didn't seem to cause this error. Regardless, I've uninstalled it but still no fix.

I am able to open other projects.

*Edit for clarity* The IDE hangs when the startup window tries to load on screen. I've tried adding the parameter -np to the shortcut target to stop loading the last loaded project. But then going to the dpr file from inside Delphi causes the program to hang when the unit I was last in tries loading.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? I'm trying to avoid a full re-install as this is a complicated procedure in our organisation.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much we could do without actually being at your computer. Can you share the source of your project file, if it's not too big?

Comment: I'm afraid not as it's company information. I'm looking into deleting my user settings that might be causing the error.

Comment: "my project will not open up in Delphi" isn't very descriptive. What **does** it do?

Comment: The IDE hangs when the startup window tries to load on screen. I've tried adding the parameter -np to the shortcut target to stop loading the last loaded project. But then going to the dpr file from inside Delphi causes the program to hang when the unit I was last in tries loading.

Comment: I saw D7 hangs when loading projects from newer delphi editions. Perhaps it is about Unicode in DFMs. try removing all text values in DFM files and loading PAS files one by one, not DPR file

Comment: It isn't a project from a newer edition. I'd been developing fine up until today when my machine blue screened. This is where the problems first started happening from.

Comment: revert project to the situation before bluescreen into CLEAN EMPTY FOLDER by you version contol system and check if problems got away. // also again - open PAS files instead of th whole project and see which file causes the freese

Comment: You should mention the bluescreen in your question

Comment: @Chucky:  Have you tried deleting your project's .Dsk file (while the ide is closed, of course)?

Comment: Of course @MartynA meant **renaming** your .dsk file instead of *deleting*.

Comment: Inspect your project file (dpr, dsk) with a simple text editor, compare them with a working project.

Comment: Start a new project and add the units and data modules to it.

Comment: @JanDoggen may not work for binary DFMs

Comment: try debugging the debugger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644052/how-to-debug-delphi-ide

Comment: I have fixed the issue, I will elaborate asap as I still have some further questions regarding my fix.